# Infinite, residually-finite, finitely generated, groups with very limited composition factors of their finite images.

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $S$ be a finite collection of finite non-abelian simple groups, for example $S=\{ A_5 \}$. I am looking for infinite residually-finite finitely-generated groups $G$ such that the composition factors of each finite image of $G$ are in $S$. Are there such examples?

Comment: You might want to include a link to the definition of "composition factors", e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek I believe composition factors is a very standard term, but thank you for the link.

Comment: One approach would be to consider the infinite iterated wreath product of A_5 acting a 5-regular rooted tree and try to find a finitely generated subgroup with the congruence subgroup property. For branch groups there are some easy conditions to check congruence subgroup so maybe you can build one.

Comment: Remark: such $G$ cannot be elementary amenable. Indeed, any infinite, finitely generated, elementary amenable $G$ admits all cyclic groups of prime order occur as composition factor of some finite image (because $G$ has an infinite virtually abelian quotient).

Comment: There are a few known infinite residually finite finitely generated $G$ I am aware with finitely many isomorphism types of composition factors of finite quotients. The firsts I can think of are infinite residually finite finitely generated $p$-groups, and occur among branch/self-similar groups. In these case, the composition factors are abelian, but hopefully this is a good approach, looking at action on larger trees (as also suggested by Benjamin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theorem 1.27 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510294.pdf gives 63-generated, residually finite, just infinite groups with the property you want for any set of simple nonabelian groups. The construction is due to Dan Segal.  See Dan Segal, The finite images of finitely generated groups, Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 82 (2001), no. 3, 597–613.

**Original Answer.** Peter Neumann constructed finitely generated just infinite branch groups all of whose finite quotients are iterated permutational wreath products of $A_6$ and hence have only $A_6$ as a composition factor. See example 1.6.6 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510294.pdf.

Comment: Could you leave your previous example? it's much older and already answers the question.

Comment: Ok. It does it for only on family of simple groups though.